# Pandas sqlalchemy to Oracle Error Insert ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to insert into an Oracle 12.2 DB. I am getting this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
> 56-57: ordinal not in range(128)

For simplification, I created a one column table and the value that is giving an error is also displayed as an example. This valueIi am able to insert from Toad/SQL plus.

#Table structure

```
create table TMI_TEST(Col_1 VARCHAR2(120))

conn = create_engine(oracle_url,  encoding='UTF-8')
col_values = 'Psychology Â¿ Non-Majors'
conn.execute("INSERT INTO SYSADM.TMI_TEST (COL_1 ) VALUES( " + col_values + ")" )
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
> 56-57: ordinal not in range(128)

How to fix this error?

Comment: what is the characterset of the database? (look in v$nls_parameters)

Comment: Hi, the characterset is AL32UTF8 and i am able to insert the above mentioned row from Toad in to the DB.

Comment: I would imagine the characters in col_values would not be compatible with the way the table was defined in Oracle.

Comment: Are you sure your code is ok? I think it lacks a single-quote around the value passed, i.e. VALUES ('"+col_values+"')"))

Comment: Hi , i tried the column to be NVARCHR2 , but still getting the same  error, if i remove the character "Â¿" then the row is inserted into the table.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was solved after i added os.environ['NLS_LANG']= 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'